# MIPS Assembly - Matrix multiplication issue, not adding the last column

Tags: assembly, matrix, mips, matrix-multiplication

I'm writing a simple program that multiply two matrices in mips assembly. However it does not show the correct output as it does not add correctly the numbers in the first and third column. I'm new to assembly programming and I would appreciate some help!

Here's the code:

```
.data
matrizA:    .space 9
matrizB:    .space 9
matrizC:    .space 9
DIM2:       .byte 09    #DIM*DIM (3*3 = 9) 
DIM:        .byte 03    #Matrix Dimension = 3

messageInput1:   .asciiz "Ingresa elemento de la Matriz A (POSITIVO):  "
messageInput2:   .asciiz "Ingresa elemento de la Matriz B (POSITIVO):   "
resultMessage:   .asciiz "Valor de multiplicacion (solo para verificar) :  "
finalResultMessage:   .asciiz "Resultado FINAL de multiplicacion :  "
error:       .asciiz "[ERROR]\nValores positivos.\n"        
jump:        .asciiz "\n"                       
.align 2

.text

.globl main     #START IN MAIN...

main:
    la      $t0, DIM2       
    lbu $t0, 0($t0)     
    la      $t1, DIM        
    lbu $t1, 0($t1)     

    la      $a0, messageInput1      # Carga en a0 la cadena de mensaje...
    la      $a1, matrizA        # Carga la direccion de A[0] en a1...
    add     $a2, $a1, $t0       # Checa la dimension + la direccion, el limite, en a2...
    jal     captura             # Llama la funcion de captura...#Captura matriz B...
    la      $a0, messageInput2      # Carga en a0 la cadena de mensaje...
    la      $a1, matrizB        # Carga la direccion de A[0] en a1...
    add     $a2, $a1, $t0       # Checa la dimension + la direccion, el limite, en a2...
    jal     captura             # Llama la funcion de captura...

        xor     $t2, $t2, $t2   # i = 0

fori:   xor     $t3, $t3, $t3   # j = 0s

forj:   xor     $t8, $t8, $t8   #k = 0


fork:   mul     $t4, $t1, $t2   # temp = DIM * i
    add     $t4, $t4, $t3   # temp = i * DIM + j

     la      $t5, matrizA   # Carga en t5 la direccion de A[0]...
     add     $t5, $t5, $t4   # temp += direccion de A[0]
     lbu     $t6, 0($t5)    # Carga A[temp] en t6...
     lbu     $t7, 9($t5)    # carga B[temp] en t7...

     mul    $t6, $t6, $t7   # C[temp] = A[temp] * B[temp]
     add    $t6, $t6, $t6
     sb      $t6, 18($t5)   # Guarda... C[temp]



     addi    $t8, $t8, 1     # k++
     bne     $t8, $t1, fork  # k < DIM? Continua el ciclo en k....

     addi    $t3, $t3, 1     # j++
     bne     $t3, $t1, forj  # j < DIM? Continua el ciclo en j...

     addi    $t2, $t2, 1     # i++
     bne     $t2, $t1, fori  # i < DIM? Continua el ciclo en i....


     la      $t1, matrizC   # Carga direccion de C[0]...
     add     $t2, $t0, $t1   # Añade dimension...

 display:li      $v0,4           # Muestra mensaje de resultado...
         la      $a0, resultMessage
         syscall

         lbu     $a0, 0($t1)     # Carga el valor del resultado...
         li      $v0,1           
    syscall 

    li      $v0,4           #Imprime un salto : '\n'
    la      $a0, jump
    syscall

    addi    $t1, $t1, 1         # Incrementa el index...
    bne     $t2, $t1, display       # i < DIM? 

    li      $v0,10          #System call (v0-10), salida...
    syscall



 captura:move    $s0, $a0      
         li      $v0,4           # PRINT STRING SYSTEM (v0-4)
         syscall                 # $a0 ya esta cargada, imprime...

    li      $v0,5           # READ INTEGER SYSTEM (v0-5)
    syscall 

    bgtz    $v0, validaPositivo    # Checa si el numero es positivo...

    li      $v0,4               #Si no, imprime el ERROR...
    la      $a0, error      #Mensaje de Error en 10...
    syscall

    move    $a0, $s0            # Recupera el string original...
    j       captura             valido...

 validaPositivo: 
         sb      $v0, 0($a1)        # Guarda el valor de la matriz A...
         addi    $a1, $a1, 1        # Incrementa el apuntador index...
         bne     $a2, $a1, captura  #Si NO es igual...

         jr      $ra             # Regresa a la funcion que te llamo...
```

As I said, Im'm really new to assembly programming and I don't know where the program is failling. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To find out where the program is failing, use a debugger.

Comment: I did it and apparently the misbehaviour is in the third loop (fork:), it's not doing the proper add, but I don't know how to implement it in the right way.